# Locally caching specific artifacts in Nexus

Tags: maven, nexus

I am currently evaluating Nexus to see if it can meet the requirements for our company. I can't seem to find what I need in the manual, so I thought I would ask before giving up on it.

We have a strict requirement that only specifically authorized OSS libraries (and their dependencies) can be used for development. We would like to achieve this without giving up automatic resolution of transitive dependencies, so Nexus seemed like a good tool for this.

The idea is that we could keep all of our proxied repositories in "Blocked" mode, thus allowing Nexus to serve locally cached artifacts, but refusing to go out to the Internet if a build asks for something that is not already cached.

The "OSS Manager" (person) would then log in with his admin id, take the repositories out of "Blocked" mode, and then somehow tell Nexus to download the list of libraries that he wants to authorize. After all the libraries and their dependencies have been locally cached, he would place the repositories back into "Blocked" mode.

I can't seem to find a way to tell Nexus to download a library and it dependencies from the UI. The "OSS Manager" is not a developer, so setting up a custom Maven or Gradle build every time they want to add authorized libraries is not an option.

Can I achieve this with bare Nexus (or maybe a plugin?), or do I need to write a custom app that the "OSS Manager" will use to generate a fake Maven build based on the list of desired libraries, and then run that build against the Nexus instance while it is in "Unblocked" state?

Comment: Nexus Pro feature called the procurement suite: https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/procure.html

Comment: Strangely enough, the Procurement Suite still falls short of allowing an administrator to procure a specific artifact and all of its dependencies. All it does is set up simple Rules for matching on artifact names to allow or disallow for procurement. Resolving dependencies is still left up to an external build, meaning that the "OSS Manager" cannot do his job without direct support from a developer.

Comment: It's a complex topic with no simple answer. Fact is the dependency tree for each project is more or less unique and dependent on which version of which dependency is selected in a particular POM. The rules generated by Sonatype need to be generated externally. I would suggest talking to Sonatype who have other commerical licence management software

Answer (score -1):

Normal Nexus proxy repositories download modules when those modules are requested.  For example, in Python, one would execute the following in order to download the *pytest* module and all its dependencies:

```
george@my-box 10:34 ~/src/myproj> pip install pytest
Looking in indexes: http://10.1.2.3/nexus/repository/pypi-proxy/simple
Collecting pytest
  Downloading http://10.1.2.3/nexus/repository/pypi-proxy/packages/7e/16/83b2a35c427b838df9836c9e7e4ae6dfbcbdea643db44652f693b1c57d70/pytest-4.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (223kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 225kB 43.3MB/s 
Collecting pluggy>=0.9 (from pytest)
  Downloading http://10.1.2.3/nexus/repository/pypi-proxy/packages/84/e8/4ddac125b5a0e84ea6ffc93cfccf1e7ee1924e88f53c64e98227f0af2a5f/pluggy-0.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting more-itertools>=4.0.0; python_version > "2.7" (from pytest)
  Downloading http://10.1.2.3/nexus/repository/pypi-proxy/packages/b3/73/64fb5922b745fc1daee8a2880d907d2a70d9c7bb71eea86fcb9445daab5e/more_itertools-7.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (53kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 30.9MB/s 
Collecting atomicwrites>=1.0 (from pytest)
  Downloading http://10.1.2.3/nexus/repository/pypi-proxy/packages/52/90/6155aa926f43f2b2a22b01be7241be3bfd1ceaf7d0b3267213e8127d41f4/atomicwrites-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting attrs>=17.4.0 (from pytest)
  Downloading http://10.1.2.3/nexus/repository/pypi-proxy/packages/23/96/d828354fa2dbdf216eaa7b7de0db692f12c234f7ef888cc14980ef40d1d2/attrs-19.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in /home/george/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pytest) (1.11.0)
Collecting py>=1.5.0 (from pytest)
  Downloading http://10.1.2.3/nexus/repository/pypi-proxy/packages/76/bc/394ad449851729244a97857ee14d7cba61ddb268dce3db538ba2f2ba1f0f/py-1.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (83kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 34.8MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /home/george/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pytest) (40.2.0)
Installing collected packages: pluggy, more-itertools, atomicwrites, attrs, py, pytest
Successfully installed atomicwrites-1.3.0 attrs-19.1.0 more-itertools-7.0.0 pluggy-0.9.0 py-1.8.0 pytest-4.4.0
```

Thus the procedure to cache the *pytest* module and all required dependencies for your users would be:

1. Unblock the pypi-proxy repository
2. Execute `pip install pytest`
3. Block the pypi-proxy repository

Comment: This is equivalent to setting up a Maven or Gradle build every time we want to add some dependencies. My question was asking how to avoid that.

Comment: You're right.  This could be a simple shell script that would prompt the user for each library to install, but if you can't trust the OSS Manager at the command line, it's a non-starter.  My bad.